# Armazenar dados de um array em uma variavel

Tags: array, ruby, csv

Tenho um arquivo CSV com as informações conforme abaixo:

```
nome;cpf;ano;faculdade;
Pedro Sampaio;45896588963;2010;fmu;
Yuri Martins;45885485896;2012;uninove;
Pablo Vittar;32585296363;2020;unip;
```

Realizei a leitura desse arquivo utilizando o código abaixo, para pegar somente o nome "Pedro Sampaio"

```
require "csv"
path = "importador.csv"
option = { :encoding => "UTF-8", :skip_blanks => true, col_sep: "," }
array_students = CSV.read(path, options)
puts array_students[1][0][0..12]
```

Tentei usar o CSV.foreach porém não consgui chegar ao resultado de localizar somente o nome como consegui com o read, porém sei que cada pessoa pode ter um nome maior ou menor ao do Pedro Sampaio e estou com dificuldade para pegar o nome e adicionar em uma variável.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com a sua resposta você já tem uma array onde o indice [0] vem todo o conteúdo do CSV, certo?

O que precisa fazer é, transformar isso em um array e depois separar em blocos.

Como fazer isso?

Você primeiro vai transformar o conteudo do array_students[0] para um array usando o `split()`

```
arrays = array_students[0].split(";")
```

e depois separar esse array em blocos de 4

```
arrays = arrays.each_slice(4).to_a
```

Com isso, você pode usar um for para percorrer esse array com cada linha do csv, para exibir o nome do student, por exemplo.

```
for student in arrays do
    puts student[0]
end
```

E o resultado seria:

*nome

Pedro Sampaio

Yuri Martins

Pablo Vittar*

que você pode usar como quiser salvando o `student[0]` numa variável ou em outra lista.

Aqui nesse link vc pode checar o código rodando
https://repl.it/repls/CheerfulRegalDiskdrive

Comment: Talvez eu não tenha entendido muito bem suas explicação, vou colocar o que fiz como resposta porque o tamanho não é permitido aqui.

Comment: Eu atualizei a resposta e coloquei um link com o código pra vc ver como foi feito.

Comment: ah, sua forma ficou muito mais simples, depois de uma sofrência eu consegui chegar a uma solução porém com muito mais código. Vou compartilhar aqui também: https://repl.it/@seuvitoo/leitor